# Mark questions for FAQ on related tag

Tags: feature-request

This is related to the "mark as duplicate" feature.

Good questions (upvoted) with really good answers (upvoted), should be potentially used as "FAQ" on the related tag, and encourage the users to read them when writing a question.

In case the algorithm isn't clear to recommend questions as FAQ, probably we can have a feature to "Mark as FAQ for #TAG".

**Example:**
An example could be found in this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22617143/335905

The problem is that Response.BinaryWrite(byte[]) doesn't do anything neither throw errors.

The answer is simple: "Are you working with updatepanels?".  You can't flag the question as duplicate (at least not initially), because the question usually don't involves panels in the title or main content.

Take a look at this searches

1. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Response.BinaryWrite       |    **1,465 results**

Now, where the answer was found but don't marked as duplicated:
 2. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Response.BinaryWrite+updatepanel | **23 results**

The FAQ on related tags could rise the attention to us as programmers, even better than the "relevant questions" when we are writing one.

Comment: Somewhat similar to the frequent tab on tag pages?

Comment: Sorry but I failed to see how this is related to mark as duplicate?

Comment: It involves tagging a question/answer... just like flagging as duplicate involves tagging a question

Comment: @ShadowWizard see my edit.

Comment: That's not possible or feasible. Tag wiki (which you refer to as FAQ, which it isn't) can't possibly contain debugging information.